# Best way to combine string and placemark data for NSUrl?

Tags: nsstring

I'm trying to get the temp and weather data for my app based on the latitude and longitude location...

How can I get this to work?

```
    NSURL *jsonurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=(API-KEY)&output=json&query=",placemark.location,@"&temp_unit=f"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *jsonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=(API-KEY)&output=json&query=%@&temp_unit=f", placemark.location];
NSURL *jsonurl = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonStr];
```

This assumes that the value for `placemark.location` is an NSString that only contains valid URL characters.